# Maximize Summation of Selected Numbers from Matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization

I have the following matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1.00&0.75&0.50&0.25\\1.00&0.35&0.22&0.44\\0.33&0.45&0.33&1.00\end{bmatrix}$$

I need to take a number from each row and then sum them together. The numbers chosen should maximize the summation of them. There is one condition though if a number is selected at a certain position in one of the rows, I cannot select another number from this position in the other rows. For example, if number 1.00 is selected from the first row, I cannot select number 1.00 from the second row since it is in the same position.

For this example, the perfect combination would be 0.75 - 1.00 - 1.00

Is there any algorithm to find these numbers without brute forcing all possibilities?

Comment: I think brute force is the only way, unless the matrix has a special structure (e.g., elements on the main diagonal are known to be larger than off-diagonal).

Comment: Look up the Assignment (or Allocation) problem. Normally done as a minimization problem but maximization is a minor tweek.

Comment: 1. Add a row of 0's to make the problem square. 2. Subtract the largest number in each row from all numbers in that row. 3 If a row has one 0 in it put a box round it and cross out the column. Ignoring anything crossed out, repeat for all rows. Repeat for all columns (cross out rows) until you have no unboxed or uncrossed 0's. 4. You get 3 boxed 0's and 6 uncrossed numbers. Add the smallest of the 6 values to the each uncrossed value (creates a 0). Subtract this number from any number crossed twice. Return to step 3. Iterate if required.